# Changing library search paths by install_name_tool

Tags: macos, rpath, install-name-tool

`otool -L` dependencies for a binary:

```
$ otool -L libeditorlib.dylib 
libeditorlib.dylib:
    libeditorlib.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libnlopt.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.10.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openvdb/lib/libopenvdb.8.0.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.1)
    /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libHalf-2_5.25.dylib (compatibility version 25.0.0, current version 25.0.4)
    /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 15.0.0, current version 15.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    @rpath/QtQuickControls2.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickControls2 (compatibility version 5.12.0, current version 5.12.4)
```

Some dependencies are inside `/usr/local/opt/`. I want to change them so that the `@rpath/` is searched for them instead.

I would have to change them one-by-one like this:

```
$ install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/openvdb/lib/libopenvdb.8.0.dylib  @rpath/libopenvdb.8.0.dylib libeditorlib.dylib
```

Is there a convenient way to change all `/user/local/opt/...` to `@rpath`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the *install_name* for each library one-by-one. I wish I could find an easier way to do so:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks/.  libeditorlib.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/openvdb/lib/libopenvdb.8.0.dylib   @rpath/libopenvdb.8.0.dylib     libeditorlib.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libHalf-2_5.25.dylib   @rpath/libHalf-2_5.25.dylib     libeditorlib.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib        @rpath/libgmp.10.dylib      libeditorlib.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib           @rpath/libmpfr.6.dylib      libeditorlib.dylib
```